# Can't use addHours for Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to set the start date of an appointment reading it from a textbox, this is my code:

```
var start_temp = $('#start-datetime').val()
var start = new Date(start_temp.toString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'));
var currentMin = parseInt(start.toString('mm'));

if (currentMin > 0 && currentMin < 15)
    start.set({ 'minute': 15 });
else if (currentMin > 15 && currentMin < 30)
    start.set({ 'minute': 30 });
else if (currentMin > 30 && currentMin < 45)
    start.set({ 'minute': 45 });
else
    start.addHours(1).set({ 'minute': 0 });

$('#start-datetime').val(start.toString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'));
```

How you can see I get the start date in my textbox `start-datetime` this is filled previously with the information of the appointment. But this is not important now.

later I pass this value to the `start` variable, convert into date object and set the format of the date. But I get this:

> Invalid Date

If I print this: `$('#start-datetime).val()` I get:

> 20/11/2015 12:15

what am I doing wrong?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L0urzpp6/1/)

Comment: What other library are you using? Date.toString('mask') is non-standard and would return the whole date

Comment: You don't have to use toString method, you have to convert it to ISO format, writing na answer

Comment: I'm using Date.js and I also have moment.js but I don't use momen.js in this particular case

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net so we can get to grips with what it's doing - Thanks

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing atm.

Comment: Try to use only one Date library, remove Date.js and use moment.js that is actually updated and lighter.

Comment: Sure, give me a moment for replicate this. Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/st77vyLg/ an answer have been accepted, but I made a no library version of it, in case someone needs it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Date.js please take advantage of `Date.parse`

```
var start = Date.parse($('#start-datetime').val());
```

or in moment.js

```
// this creates a moment object (PARSED)
var start = moment($('#start-datetime').val());    
var start_string = start.format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
```

Comment: Infact, seems that .toString() broke the code or something like. Anyway, with your hint seems working fine.

Comment: toString is unnecessery

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method of doing it without any libraries.

https://jsfiddle.net/st77vyLg/1/

```
//read the string
var start_temp = document.getElementById('start-datetime').value.split('/');
//get the data out of it
day=start_temp[0];
month=start_temp[1];
start_temp=start_temp[2].split(" ");
year=start_temp[0];
start_temp=start_temp[1].split(":");
hour=start_temp[0];
minute=start_temp[1];
//make a date variable
var start = new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute);
alert(start);
```

Comment: You would still need jQuery for that first line - or change it to `var start_temp = document.getElementById('start-datetime').value.split('/');`

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be this line:

```
var start = new Date(start_temp.toString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'));
```

start_temp is just a String (as returned by `jQuery.val()` in line 1). I'm pretty sure calling `.toString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')` on it doesn't actually do anything, you just get your original string back. So then what happens is:

```
new Date('20/11/2015 12:15')
```

And that's not a valid Date format. I'm not all that familiar with Date.js but perhaps you meant to use `'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'` as the second parameter to `new Date()` rather than the first parameter to `toString()`?

Comment: have you tried this before posting? this is tottaly wrong

Comment: I have tested what I said, yes. Perhaps you misunderstand.  The code samples I give are illustrating what the OP's code is doing, not what the correct code should be. `$('#start-datetime').val()` will return a String. calling `.toString([anything])` on that is going to get you back exactly the same string, as your comment in @abc123's answer seems to support. So then the OP's code then calls `new Date()`, passing in that string (which as they said is "20/11/2015 12:15"). That returns "Invalid Date". I said "perhaps" they could try a 2nd arg to `new Date()`, I didn't promise it would work.